# split UIImage by colors and create 2 images

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have looked through replacing colors in an image but cannot get it to work how i need because I am trying to do it with every color but one, as well as transparency.

what I am looking for is a way to take in an image and split out a color (say all the pure black) from that image. Then take that split out portion and make a new image with a transparent background and the split out portion.

(here is just an example of the idea, say i want to take a screenshot of this page. make every other color but pure black be transparent, and save that new image to the library, or put it into a UIImageView)

i have looked in to CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors but cant seem to do what I need with the transparent portion, and I dont really understand the colorMasking input other than you can provide it with a {Rmin,Rmax,Gmin,Gmax,Bmin,Bmax} color mask but when I do, it colors everything. any ideas or input would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're going to have to get access to the underlying bytes and write code to process them directly. You can use `CGImageGetDataProvider()` to get access to the data of an image, but there's no guarantee that the format will be something you know how to handle. Alternately you can create a new `CGContextRef` using a specific format you know how to handle, then draw the original image into your new context, then process the underlying data. Here's a quick attempt at doing what you want (uncompiled):

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithBlackPixels:(UIImage *)image {
    CGImageRef cgImage = image.CGImage;
    // create a premultiplied ARGB context with 32bpp
    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(cgImage);
    size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(cgImage);
    size_t bpc = 8; // bits per component
    size_t bpp = bpc * 4 / 8; // bytes per pixel
    size_t bytesPerRow = bpp * width;
    void *data = malloc(bytesPerRow * height);
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Host;
    CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(data, width, height, bpc, bytesPerRow, colorspace, bitmapInfo);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
    if (ctx == NULL) {
        // couldn't create the context - double-check the parameters?
        free(data);
        return nil;
    }
    // draw the image into the context
    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), cgImage);
    // replace all non-black pixels with transparent
    // preserve existing transparency on black pixels
    for (size_t y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        size_t rowStart = bytesPerRow * y;
        for (size_t x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            size_t pixelOffset = rowStart + x*bpp;
            // check the RGB components of the pixel
            if (data[pixelOffset+1] != 0 || data[pixelOffset+2] != 0 || data[pixelOffset+3] != 0) {
                // this pixel contains non-black. zero it out
                memset(&data[pixelOffset], 0, 4);
            }
        }
    }
    // create our new image and release the context data
    CGImageRef newCGImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
    CGContextRelease(ctx);
    free(data);
    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newCGImage scale:image.scale orientation:image.imageOrientation];
    CGImageRelease(newCGImage);
    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: this solution is very close. the only things i had to change was void* data to unsigned char* data. so i could access the int values in data. and the data was showing rgba values not argb so i made data[pixelOffset+3] into data[pixelOffset]. otherwise great work. thanks!

Comment: Ah yes, the perils of not compiling code. I think the reason it was RGBA is because `kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst` turns out to store it in the most significant bits first, not the lowest-addressed bits. Specifying an explicit endianness instead of using Host would probably be a good idea at this point.